# Selecting certain groups of elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I have some grouped `<li>` tags as follows in my webpage.

```
<ul id="dg">
   <!-- group-1 -->
   <li data-group="one">....</li>
   <li data-group="one">....</li>
   <li data-group="one">....</li>
   <li data-group="one">....</li>

   <!-- group-2 -->
   <li data-group="two">....</li>
   <li data-group="two">....</li>

   <!-- group-3 -->
   <li data-group="three">....</li>

   <!-- group-4 -->
   <li data-group="four">....</li>
   <li data-group="four">....</li>
   <li data-group="four">....</li>
</ul>
```

Likewise I have around 20(Its dynamic) groups of `<li>` tags which categorized using the 'data-group'. Each category having different amount of `<li>` tags.

What I want to do is, I want to select every 4th group(data-group) and add a CSS class named 'edge' to all of its `<li>` tags using jQuery or Add a CSS property using nth.

Please help me fix this.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Do you mean : every group with 4 li? Or every li with data-group="four"? Or group 1, then 5, then 9, ...?

Comment: I want to select every 4th data-group like <li data-group="four">, <li data-group="eight">, <li data-group="twelve"> and so on....

Comment: And the group name are as you have written in your question until "twenty"?

Comment: Its dynamic, it can be any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

You can't simply use a selector. You must loop through all your `li` and deduce if they are belonging to the groups you want

```
var currentGroup = ""; //Name of the group currently checked 
var counter = 0; //Number of group found

//Loop through the items
$('#dg li').each(function(){
    //Check if we are checking a new group
    if(currentGroup != $(this).attr('data-group'))
    {
        //If yes, save the name of the new group
        currentGroup = $(this).attr('data-group');
        //And increment the number of group found
        counter++;
    }

    //If the number of the group is a multiple of 4, add the class you want
    if((counter % 4) == 0)
        $(this).addClass('edge');
});
```

Comment: Love you my friend.. Thank you very much. this works like a charm. I would appreciate if you can explain a bit(some comments after the code lines) as I could not get this.

Comment: If you know the limit of the number of groups, I would probably just manually only run through the groups you want, to avoid needlessly looping through items you don't want.

Comment: I have added some comments

Answer (score 1):

So something like:

```
$('li[data-group="four"]').each(function(){
    $(this).addClass('edge');
});
```

Is that what you mean?

So more like:

```
function processItems(items){
    items.each(function(){
        $(this).addClass('edge');
    });
}
processItems($('li[data-group="four"]'));
processItems($('li[data-group="eight"]'));
processItems($('li[data-group="twelve"]'));
```

I am unaware of the performance gain or doing something like this, but looping through each and every `li` item could be bad AND slow depending on the number of them in your list. Not saying what I have here is the BEST way, but if you have hundreds of li items, your loop could run slowly.

Comment: Similar to this but I need to select every 4th group. There around 20 groups so I need to select 4, 8, 12, 16 and so on....